# Weakly dense subset spans the space?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

If a set $\mathcal{S}$ is weakly dense in a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, is it true that $\mathcal{H}=Span(\mathcal{S})$?
I am trying to use this to show that separatability and weak separatability are equivalent, but I can't see why this claim is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any dense set is weakly dense and a dense set need not span the whole space. For example the space of finitely non-zero sequences is weakly dense in $\ell^{2}$.
However it is true that the close subspace spanned by a weakly dense set is equal to the whole space.

This last fact follows from the following: if $x_n \to x$ weakly in a Banach space then there exist a sequence of convex combinations of $x_n$'s which converges to $x$ in the norm. Equivalently, the weak closure of  a convex set equals its norm closure.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was following a claim from "A Hilbert Space Problem Book" and it seems to be wrong. I will try to see if closed=weakly closed helps to show the separability claim.

Answer (score 0):

Kavi`s answer solves my main concern here, and the last fact noticed in the answer also gives a proof of the equivalence of two types of separability.

Given $x_{n}\rightarrow x$ weakly, one construction of the converging sequence is $y_{k}=(x_{n_{1}}+...+x_{n_{k}})/k$ for some well chosen $x_{n_{i}}\in(x_{n})$. Thus, if a countable set $\mathcal S$ is weakly dense, the collection of $(x_{1}+...+x_{k})/k$ of any k and any choices of $x_{i}\in\mathcal S$ is a countable dense set. So weak separable implies separable. Converse is trivial.